# Runtime complexity of power set

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have an algo that runs in 
`T(n) = n x C(n, n) + (n-1) x C(n, n-1) + ... + 1 x C(n, 1) + 0`. How to calculate the `Big O` notation for this?

```
C(n, k) = Number of ways to select k elements from a n element array. 
C(4, 4) = 1
C(4, 3) = 4
C(4, 2) = 6
```

For n=3:

`T(3) = (3) + (2 + 2 + 2) + (1 + 1 + 1) + (0)`

`Len = 2^3 = 8`

For n=4:

`T(4) = 4*1 + 3*4 + 2*6 + 1*4 + 0`

`Len = 2^4 = 16`

Length of the series is `2^n`. But I am stuck at this point. If values of each position is `k`, we can conclude the complexity is `O(k * 2^n)`. But the values are different. I guess we can say it's `O(n * 2^n)` but I feel that is not tight. Even if it's tight bound, I am not able to explain how.

Comment: what is supposed to be C(x,y)?

Comment: @Berto99 updated the question to include detail